# GCDAsyncSockets, get answer

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcdasyncsocket

I'm trying to test a server connection with the GCDAsyncSocket.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

I want to connect to a ip + port and get a message, whether it worked, or not.

I'm so far right now.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

```
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];


    NSString *host = @"www.google.de";
    uint16_t port = 21;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if(![asyncSocket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR %@!!!", error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NO ERROR %@!!!", error);
    }

    [asyncSocket writeData:@"DATA" withTimeout:3 tag:0];

return YES;
```

}

But how can i check whether the Data was written or not?

if(![asyncSocket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&error])

always get me a no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `socket:didWriteDataWithTag:` delegate method.
From "GCDAsyncSocket.h":

```
/**
 * Called when a socket has completed writing the requested data. Not called if there is an error.
**/
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag;
```

If the write times out then the connection is closed and the delegate method

```
- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err;
```

is called.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
If i implement the methods in my AppDelegate.m how can I call the method? I never worked with delegate methods.
Greets

Comment: @shizophren: It works the other way around: the GCDAsyncSocket library calls your delegate method.

Comment: Could you be mor clearer? Where I should implement the method? And do I have to call it for myself, or will it done automatically by the GCDAsyncSocket library? I only want to know  - success, or not.

Comment: @shizophren: You have to implement the delegate methods. If you init the socket using `... initWithDelegate:self ... ` in your AppDelegate.m, then this AppDelegate is the delegate of the socket. So you implement the delegate methods in the same AppDelegate class. The GCDAsyncSocket library will call the delegate methods. `socket:didWriteDataWithTag:` is called if the write succeeded, and `socketDidDisconnect:withError` is called if the write failed.

Comment: Ok, it becomes clearer to me :-) So i implemented the two methods. They should return an NSLog Massege for me. The socketDidDisconnect seems to work, the didWriteDataWithTag not. Both only have a NSLog statement in it. Any clue why?

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag
{
 NSLog(@"didWriteDataWithTag was successfull %lu", tag);
}

- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
 NSLog(@"ERROR to Connection %@", err);
}

Comment: @shizophren: I made a quick test by modifying the sample project "CocoaAsyncSocket-master/GCD/Xcode/ConnectTest/Mobile/ConnectTest" and everything seems to work for me.